# Laravel - How to calculate number of holidays between two days

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I want to extract the number of holidays between 2 dates in another table in the database. I have 2 tables basically:

1. hr_leave_requests
2. hr_holidays

   ```
    class HrHoliday extends Model
    {
     protected $table = 'hr_holidays';
      protected $fillable = [
     'holiday_name',
     'holiday_date',
     'created_at',
    ];
   }

   class HrLeaveRequest extends Model
   {
       protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';
       protected $fillable = [
         'id',
         'commencement_date',
         'resumption_date',
       ];
   }
   ```

In my Controller I have:

```
        $commencementDate   = Carbon::parse($request->commencement_date);
        $resumptionDate     = Carbon::parse($request->resumption_date);
        $holidays = DB::table('hr_holidays')->select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();

        $commencementDate  and  $resumptionDate  are from hr_leave_requests
```

How do I complete this query:

```
$holidays = DB::table('hr_holidays')->select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
```

to get the number of holidays between  $commencementDate  and  $resumptionDate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have access to `whereBetween()` in your query.

```
$holidays = DB::table('hr_holidays')->select('holiday_date')->whereBetween('holiday_date', [$commencementDate, $resumptionDate])->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $commencementDate = Carbon::parse($request->commencement_date)
            ->startOfDay()        // 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000
            ->toDateTimeString(); // 2020-01-01 00:00:00

 $resumptionDate = Carbon::parse($request->resumption_date)
            ->endOfDay()          // 2020-04-11 23:59:59.000000
            ->toDateTimeString(); // 2020-04-11 23:59:59

$holidays  = HrHoliday::whereHas('HrLeaveRequest', function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
            $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to]);
        })->get();


    dd($holidays);
```

Hope this helps..